# Comparing two different Power Point presentations side by side

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to run two MS Office Power Point  2007 presentations side by side on two monitors on the same system . So they can be compared. But power Point will not allow two instances at the same time. Does anyone know of a trick without installing two copies of Power point on the same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Alex has the right idea, but let me help more:

After Arrange All, you can extend PowerPoint to be the width of both monitors, then manipulate each PPT's window to fit into that screen's window, giving you side by side.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/powerpointtipsandfaqs/qt/811arrangeall.htm)'s what you're looking for:

> On the View tab of the ribbon, in the Window section, click on the Arrange All button.